# Why is binary_crossentropy used in this example?

Tags: keras

In this page,

```
https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/
```

the example "Multi-input and multi-output models" is to:

```
    We seek to predict how many retweets and likes a news headline will receive on Twitter. The
     main input to the model will be the headline itself, as a sequence of words, but to spice things up, 
our model will also have an auxiliary input, receiving extra data such as the time of
 day when the headline was posted, etc.
```

The task is to predict 'how many retweets and likes',so this should be multi-class classification or regression problem. But why in the sample code, the binary classification is used?

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy',
              loss_weights=[1., 0.2])
```

Here 'binary_crossentropy', not 'categorical_crossentropy'. How can a binary classification can predict 'how many retweets and likes' in this example?